# How to zoom in an image and center it?

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

Any Idea how to zoom in a image on particular point using `javascript`, `css` ? I am using `webkit` based browser.

I can zoom by specifying zoom property , like `elem.style.zoom="150%",
Main problem is I cannot center the image where I want to zoom. 
I can get the point where I want to zoom using **mouseclick**.

Comment: Do you want to just zoom it with HTML/CSS methods or do you also want to re-load the appropriately scaled image from the server?

Comment: afaik, the zoom property is not standardized and it will not be cross browser compatible.

Comment: No I want only css/javascript solution no server side interaction.

Comment: Are the sizes of image always fixed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, I would avoid the zoom css property and stick to just javascript.  I managed to throw together the following code which works pretty well for the first click, really all it needs is a little more dynamically (even a word?).

```html
        <html>
              <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
               function resizeImg (img)
               {
              var resize = 150; // resize amount in percentage
              var origH  = 200;  // original image height
              var origW  = 200; // original image width
              var mouseX = event.x;
              var mouseY = event.y;
              var newH   = origH * (resize / 100) + "px";
              var newW   = origW * (resize / 100) + "px";
             
                 // Set the new width and height
              img.style.height = newH;
              img.style.width  = newW;
              
              var c = img.parentNode;
              
              // Work out the new center
              c.scrollLeft = (mouseX * (resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
              c.scrollTop  = (mouseY * (resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
               }
             </script>
             <style type="text/css">
               #Container {
                 position:relative;
                 width:200px;
                    height:200px;
                 overflow:hidden;
               }
             </style>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="Container">
                  <img alt="Click to zoom" onclick="resizeImg(this)" 
                    src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
                </div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

It works in Google Chrome and IE, not sure about others.  Like I said hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Andy ! Cool , Now I am totally experimenting with above for my requirement , Thanks for suggestion. All I need to do is calculations and alter the height , width , position.

Comment: hey Andy , If I am going to zoom multiple times , meaning 1st click 150% zoom , next 200% then 250% , how do I work out the new center, so that it scrolls and centres properly. ??!!

Answer (score 3):

What has to be done.

1. Get the location of the click inside the image. This might seem easy but it is not because the pageX and pageY of the event hold the coordinates in regard to the document. To calculate where inside the image someone clicked you need to know the position of the image in the document. But to do this you need to factor in all the parents of it, as well as if they are relative/absolute/static positioned .. it gets messy..
2. calculate the new center (the click position scaled - the top/left position of the container)
3. scale the image and scroll the container to the new center

if you do not mind using jQuery for it then use the following (tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function(){
                $('#Container img').click(
                    function( event ){
                        var scale = 150/100;
                        var pos = $(this).offset();
                        var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
                        var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
                        var container = $(this).parent().get(0);

                        $(this).css({
                                        width: this.width*scale, 
                                        height: this.height*scale
                                    });

                        container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2 ) + clickX * scale;
                        container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2 ) + clickY * scale;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
</script>
```

and the html needed

```
<div id="Container">
   <img alt="Click to zoom" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: You could have at least have left my variable names intact when converting my code to jQuery :P

Comment: lol .. had to feel intuitive to me while i was coding ... and never remembered to adjust it afterwards ... oh well ... homework ;)

Answer (score 1):

In following code, the image is amplified at the mouse click point - the image is amplified, but the point where you clicked remains under your mouse cursor, and the size of the frame remains the same. Right-click to go back to original display ratio.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <style>
        div {
          width: 400px;
          height: 600px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        img {
          position: relative
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageOffset_x = 0;
        var imageOffset_y = 0;

        function onZoom()
        {
            var mouseInFrame_x = event.x;
            var mouseinFrame_y = event.y;
            var mouseInImage_x = imageOffset_x + mouseInFrame_x;
            var mouseInImage_y = imageOffset_y + mouseinFrame_y;
            imageOffset_x += mouseInImage_x * 0.16;
            imageOffset_y += mouseInImage_y * 0.16;

            var image = $('#container img');
            var imageWidth = image.width();
            var imageHeight = image.height();

            image.css({
                height: imageHeight * 1.2,
                width: imageWidth * 1.2,
                left: -imageOffset_x,
                top: -imageOffset_y
            });
        }

        function onRightClick() {
            imageOffset_x = 0;
            imageOffset_y = 0;

            $('#container img').css({
                height: 600,
                width: 400,
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });

            return false;
        }

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="zoom" href="#" onclick="onZoom();">Zoom</a>

    <div id="container">
        <img src="~/Images/Sampple.jpg" width="400" height="600" onclick="onZoom();" oncontextmenu="onRightClick(); return false;"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```