# ZOOMING AN IMAGE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to zoom in the image and center it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028557/how-to-zoom-in-the-image-and-center-it)

how can javascript be useful in zooming an image . I want to zoom it when we double click on it.

Comment: You should have edited your previous question rather than posting a new one.  Turns out it's a dupe anyway.

Comment: Enhance... I SAID(!) ENHANCE!

Comment: you all are commenting..I guess you all would have understood my question.. So instead of pulling leg you should help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an onclick/ondoubleclick handler to the image. When it fires, increase the image's height/width by a certain percentage.

The very basic version:

```
<img src="somepic.jpg" height="XXX" width="YYY" ondblclick="this.height *= 1.1; this.width *= 1.1" />
```

Comment: **ondoubleclick** should be **ondblclick**. And if the asker is using jQuery, **on** should be cutted off also.