# Scale and zoom an image

Tags: javascript, css, scaling, zooming

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028557/how-to-zoom-in-an-image-and-center-it) and found it helpful, but I tried doing more with the code to apply zoom buttons and can't seem to get it to work properly. I'm new to javascript and jquery and I'm having trouble understanding how the "this" keyword is applied.

```
$('#plus').click(
function( event ){
    var scale = 150/100;
    var pos = $('#Container img').offset();
    var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
    var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
    var container = $('#Container img').parent().get(0);

    $('#Container img').css({
        width: this.width*scale, 
        height: this.height*scale
    });

    container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2 ) + clickX * scale;
    container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2 ) + clickY * scale;
}
);

$('#minus').click(
function( event ){
    var scale = 100/150;
    var pos = $('#Container img').offset();
    var clickX = event.pageX - pos.left;
    var clickY = event.pageY - pos.top;
    var container = $('#Container img').parent().get(0);

    $('#Container img').css({
        width: this.width*scale, 
        height: this.height*scale
    });

    container.scrollLeft = ($(container).width() / -2 ) + clickX * scale;
    container.scrollTop = ($(container).height() / -2 ) + clickY * scale;
}
);
```

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senatorlaw/4A9Gt/1/) to demo my code.

Comment: Offtopic hint: try not to use floating point numbers in HTML/CSS (100/150 * x would produce one).

Comment: I have another jsfiddle that scales the img when it's clicked. I changed the scale to make the image smaller to 100/200 (which I believe is still a float). http://jsfiddle.net/senatorlaw/pb68K/1/

Comment: I meant to round (or floor/ceil) it, not change the scale because 100/200 * 3px = 1.5px. But anyway, it's not relevant to the problem, just wanted you to know. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. That is still very good info and I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, looks like I'll have to answer the whole thing actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the clicked element (actually, you should probably be using `$(this)` in jQuery), because the function that's called after the click gets that scope. So in your example, `this` refers to either the plus or the minus button, therefore you're techically scaling **their** width/height and applying the resulting width/height to the image.

A common thing to avoid having to debug what `this` represent is to assign it to a variable at the very top of the function, for example:

```
var self = this;
```

or

```
var $myClickedButton = this;
```

Also, pay attention to styling:

- `element.width` refers to an element's width attribute (like `<img width="300" />`, similar to jQuery's `$(element).attr('width')`), but
- `element.style.width` refers to its CSS width (like `<img style="width: 300px;" />`, or `<img class="myClassWithDenotedWidth" />`, similar to jQuery's `$(element).css('width')`). The latter also has a unit, so you have to parseInt it to get just the numeric value.

I've fixed it for your plus button, you can follow the same principle for the minus. Here's what I did:

```
    var $image = $('#Container img');
    var container = $image.parent().get(0);

    $('#Container img').css({
        width: Math.round(parseInt($image.css('width'), 10) * scale), 
        height: Math.round(parseInt($image.css('height'), 10) * scale)
    });
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/4A9Gt/4/ (also added a CSS transition to make zooms less choppy)