# use JavaScript to toggle between different "crops" of a single large image

Tags: javascript, css, image

So I have been reading up on dozens upon dozens of Javascript zoom components, but none of them do what I am looking for, so I'm curious where to find such a component (if one exists) or how to code it myself.

The goal is to download a single large (1000x1000) image to the browser. Then within the browser, the image would have three presentation states within the same element container that the user can toggle between by clicking on some page element.

State 1 (default): See the entire image, but scaled down to fit within a 500x500 container (i.e. shrunk, but not cropped). For example (not to scale, but for comparison with other states):

[image]

State 2: See the middle 50%, centered, in the same container (i.e. actual size, and cropped). For example:

[image]

State 3: See the middle 25%, centered, in the same container (i.e. enlarged, and cropped quite a bit). For example:

[image]

And I would put the script that toggles between these three states in the click of some page element, such as a button.

Can any one offer a link to a component that does this, or suggestions on how the method that might accomplish it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2029444/4515720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go down on leveraging some CSS here.

For first case:

1) create a DIV which is 500x500, and set the background image to the file. Make sure you set `background-size:contain` property as well on the div.

2) For the second case I will remove the `background-size:contain`

3) The third case I will set the `background-size:200%;'

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2ht1cn8/)

Answer (score 1):

If what you've described is really all you want to do it can be easily achieved with some CSS and a few lines of javascript:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.image-zoom'),
    zoomBtn = document.getElementById('zoom-it'),
    i = 0;

function clickHandler() {
    if (i === 0) {
        container.classList.add('zoom-2x');
        i++;
    } else if (i === 1) {
        container.classList.add('zoom-4x');
        i++;
    } else {
        container.classList.remove('zoom-2x');
        container.classList.remove('zoom-4x');
        i = 0;
    }

}

zoomBtn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```css
.image-container, .image-zoom {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-zoom.zoom-2x {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.image-zoom.zoom-4x {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image-zoom" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/250/250)">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="zoom-it">zoom image</button>
```

This assumes you know the dimensions of the image, which if you're using a CMS you can likely easily get and insert them inline on the `.image-zoom` and `.image-container`elements.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ggz2oezk/)

**EDIT**

[jsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ggz2oezk/2/)

Modified the jsfiddle to be closer to what your question asked (initial state of the image is contained within the square and not cropped any amount.)

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks. Wish I could mark two answers as solutions. I will likely use elements of this if we add more than 3 stages.